# HTML5 - canvas and dragging/dropping or placing an image where user clicks

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Okay, my first question is this:

**Is it possible to drag and drop an image on the canvas to a different place on the canvas?**

I have the image on the canvas already, I would just like the user to be able to move it by clicking and dragging. I know this is possible with Kinetic JS, but is it possible just using the regular HTML5 canvas?

Second, if the first question isn't possible:

**Is it possible for an image to be placed on a canvas at the point where a user clicks?**

Can someone help me out here, or point me in the direction of a tutorial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible to drag and drop an image on the canvas to a different place on the canvas?**
Yes. You can read more about it here - http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-an-image-tutorial/

**Is it possible for an image to be placed on a canvas at the point where a user clicks?**
Yes. You'll need to find out the co-ordinates of the canvas element that were clicked and place the image accordingly.

You can read more and view demos of the canvas element here - http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/

Comment: its clearly mentioned that he doesnt want KineticJS. ur first answer is the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

1. **Is it possible to drag and drop an image on the canvas to a different place on the canvas?**. Yes. However, if you want this, you have to implement it yourself.
2. **Is it possible for an image to be placed on a canvas at the point where a user clicks?** Yes. However, if you want this, you first have to implement 1), then implement dragging images.